# Android API 33 - How to get permission to read/write in external storage?

Tags: android

I am working on updating an existing Android app. The app offers a feature to store custom files (e.g. PDF repots, **no** image, audio or video) to the `Documents` folder on external storage `Documents/MyApp/Reports'. Additionally the app can read any such file from this folder, no matter if it was created by the app **or uploaded by the user**.

While the existing code works just fine up to API 32, **no file permission dialog is shown** when running on API 33. The handler `onRequestPermissionsResult` is called without any user interaction with denial for all requested permissions.

As @blackapps pointed out, on API 33 it is no longer necessary to ask for permissions to write and read files. While this seems to be true for files created by the app itself, I cannot access any files the user uploaded to `Documents/MyApp/Reports`. These files are simply not included in `dir.listFiles()`.

**How can I fix this?**

---

I found other questions about similar issues and some of them link to [this API 33 changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions) regarding "*Granular media permissions*". However, replacing `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` with `READ_MEDIA_IMAGES`, `READ_MEDIA_VIDEO` and `READ_MEDIA_AUDIO` is not a good solution in my case since `Allow XY to access music...` would be misleading when storing a custom, non music file.

Additionally adding these permission to the manifest and requesting them within the app, does not change anything. Custom files uploaded by the user are still not included in `dir.listFiles()`.

The same is true when add/requesting `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission instead.

**How to correctly request external storage usage for custom / non-media files?**

---

**My code:**

```
// AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


// SomeActivity.java
public class SomeActivity extends NavigationActivity {
    ...

    public boolean askForFilePermissions() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            boolean hasPermission = this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

            if (!hasPermission) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission was granted, yay!
                
                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo!
                }

                return;
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For an Android 13 device you do not need to request write permissions as you have it by default.

So your app can just create folders and files in Documents directory and all other public directories.

Comment: OK, that is good to know :-) And what about read permissions?

Comment: On Android 13 devices if you wanna read media files of other apps you use the three READ_MEDIA_ permissions you mentioned.

Comment: OK, but again: Is asking for permission "To access music..." really the correct / intended way to access custom files (e.g. PDF) created/stored by the app itself?

Comment: No. You do not need to ask for a read permission for files your app created. If you are allowed to create/write then read is allowed too.

Comment: Sorry that I have to ask again: What about custom, non-media files that have not been created by the app? My app can create AND show PDF Reports (and other files) in external storage `/Documents/MyApp/Reports/SomeReport.pdf`. Showing this files works fine, when it was created by the app itself. But when I upload a file to this dir via the file explorer, it is not visible to my app at all. The file is not included in `dir.listFiles()`. In Android versions before API 33 this is no problem. How to handle in API 33?

Comment: Those files will also not be visible on Android 11 and 12 devices. I do not believe your 'before API 33' statement.

Comment: Sorry, your are right. The question how to get permission is answered (not necessary any more). I now struggle to read foreign files. But this is a topic for another question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76161743/777861