# Android SDK 30 and above - How to open any file from external storage?

Tags: android

**TL;DR:** How to give an App access to read its own and foreign files in external storage in Android 30+?

---

### Details:

I am working on updating an existing Android app which offers a feature to:

- **write** files to external storage `file://storage/emulated/0/Documents/MyApp`
- **read** these **app created** files
- **read** placed by the user in this folder

**Problem:**

In API 30+ it is no longer possible to access "foreign" files (uploaded by the user and not created by the app). They simply are not included in `dir.listFiles()` any more. The app now only sees files it created itself.

**How can this be solved?**

#### EXTERNAL_STORAGE Permissions:

This is NOT a permissions problem. In API 30-32 it was necessary to request `READ_ + WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to let the app create custom files and read them. Even with these permission being granted, accessing foreign files is not possible.

In API 33 requesting the permission it not necessary anymore. However, accessing foreign files is still not possible.

#### READ_MEDIA permissions:

I tried to request other permissions instead: `READ_MEDIA_*` does not give me any more access. Additionally requesting these permissions asks the user if the app should access Images, Music and Video. This is misleading since I do not want to access those files but only custom document files.

#### MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Even trying to grant `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` did not solve the issue. Additionally it is not very likely that Google would accept my app if it requires this permission.

#### SAF (Storage Access Framework)

Next I tried to use SAF to let the user pick a file to give the app access to it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("*/*");

Uri pickerInitialUri = Uri.fromFile(getAppExternalStorageDir()); // file://storage/emulated/0/Documents/MyApp
intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri);

startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_BACKUP_FILE);
```

While this shows the system file/folder picker, the picker only shows those files created by the app it self. Files uploaded by the user are still not visible...

#### Register app to open custom files

My last attempt was add an `intent-filter` to the app to register it to open my `.custom` files:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.custom" />
</intent-filter>
```

This compiles without any problem, but when using the Files app to access the apps external storage dir, I can sill not open/see those files although I can see them in the Android Studio Device File Explorer.

---

Now I am out of ideas... Is there anything else I could do to let my app access custom files which have not been created by the app itself in Android 30+. Is this even possible or do I have to drop this feature?

Comment: Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT WIll show you all files. All files can be picked. Dont mess around with initial uri. You do not need any permission. You do not have to register anything. Implementing MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE would show all files in the classic way. I have no idea why normal things dont work for you.

Comment: That you dont see files of other apps has nothing to do with custom files.

Comment: hello i tried mediastore but still not getting any pdf file the file is in download folder have you get any solution yet pls share if yes it really helpful SAF also not supported i think above 33 now

Comment: Same issue here, i have create folder in document for app use in old apk , after then i want to use this folder after update app SDK version to 33 - result : Not able to access it.

Comment: Let me know if you have found something. or share here for other also. Thanks

Comment: Same issue here! I can read/write files that the application itself has created. But how to convince this darn OS to grant the app access to files that the app did not create itself? Really starting to get annoyed! How can such a simple thing, namely to be able to read files from the application's own folder, get so complicated?

Answer (score 2):

OK, here's some of what I had to add to an old app of mine to get this to work. It's an old app so it's in java but easy enough to transcode.

And, yeah, your app will need a damn good reason to use this for Google Play to allow it :( But that's the problem with the way Android is locked down nowadays.

You could always try and build a document provider for pdf's (see https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files )

Anyway, in the manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And then in the app's activity when checking permissions:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33 && !Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", this.getPackageName(), null);
            intent.setData(uri);
            startActivity(intent);
            return false;
        }
```

This link shows a bit more code (which you'll have to adjust a bit):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68168979/1138878

BTW, you might want to use the following for the permission but I could do without it whilst still accessing my files (.xml's, in my case):

```
int permissionManageStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33 && permissionManageStorage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
```